# Remove part of string after character in an array and remove repeated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove part of the value of an element in an array after '_' and once its done remove all repeated elements.

Array looks like

```
names =  ["ann_w", "james_q", "ann_q", "peter_p", "steve_q", "james_s"];
```

And I am trying to convert it into

```
names = ["ann", "james", "peter", "steve"];
```

Below code is returning undefined and cant figure it out how to remove all repeated elements.

```
for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
   names[i] = names[i].substring(names[i].indexOf("_") + 1);
}
```

Comment: yeah you are right, i forgot to put it when bringing the code her

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use Set & map:

```js
var names =  ["ann_w", "james_q", "ann_q", "peter_p", "steve_q", "james_s"];

var unique_names = [ ...new Set(names.map(name => {
   return name.split('_')[0]
}))]
console.log(unique_names)
```

Comment: [spread doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) & [Set class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: @up , tl;dr : Set guarantee uniqueness, while "..." turns Set back into Array

Comment: Syntactic sugar to decrease code: `var unique_names = [ ...new Set(names.map(name => name.split('_')[0]))];`

Comment: [ ...new Set crashes in safari and IE, what would be the alternative?

Comment: You could always transpile this beautiful code with [babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=var%20names%20%3D%20%20%5B%22ann_w%22%2C%20%22james_q%22%2C%20%22ann_q%22%2C%20%22peter_p%22%2C%20%22steve_q%22%2C%20%22james_s%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20unique_names%20%3D%20%5B%20...new%20Set(names.map(name%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20return%20name.split('_')%5B0%5D%0D%0A%7D))%5D%0D%0Aconsole.log(unique_names))

Answer (score 2):

```
var names = ["ann_w", "james_q", "ann_q", "peter_p", "steve_q", "james_s"];

var tmp = names.map(function(n){
   return n.split("_")[0];
}).sort();

// tmp = ["ann", "ann", "james", "james", "peter", "steve"]

var result = [];

tmp.forEach(function(t){
    if(!result.includes(t))
        result.push(t);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using split on the string instead of doing the substring, then you'd get an array of strings, and since you only want the first name, you'd take array[0].

Also, you're getting back errors because you're trying to substring the entire array instead of a string.  You'd need to do names[i] = names[i].substring

Answer (score 0):

You can do this: Use `array#reduce` and `Object.keys`.
`reduce` will create an object with name as keys and then you can get the key as an array via `Object.keys()`.

```js
var names =  ["ann_w", "james_q", "ann_q", "peter_p", "steve_q", "james_s"];

var obj = names.reduce(function(r,v) {
  var name = v.split('_')[0];
  if(!r[name]) {
    r[name] = 1;
  }
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(Object.keys(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var names =  ["ann_w", "james_q", "ann_q", "peter_p", "steve_q", "james_s"];
var finalArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i <names.length; i++){
var substringArray = names[i].split("_");
if(finalArray.indexOf(substringArray[0]) == -1) finalArray.push(substringArray[0]);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3z3naanb/9/

Answer (score 0):

```
names =  ["ann_w", "james_q", "ann_q", "peter_p", "steve_q", "james_s"];

for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
   names[i] = names[i].substring(0, names[i].indexOf("_"));
}

var unique = names.filter(function(item, i, names) {
    return i == names.indexOf(item);
});

console.log(unique)
```